# cant find the error in jekyll... "did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping"

Tags: html, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I'm a relative newbee to jekyll and liquid. I had this running a while ago but messed it up somehow, without a backup. When finding something the error just shifts to somewhere else... Please take a look.

Here is my code:

```
---
title: Gallery
layout: gallery
heroimage: /img/hero-image-gallery.jpg
imgsize: small
masonry:
itemsize: 33.333%
categories:
- Objects
- People
- Places
images:
- title: one
  thumb: img/gallery-image-one.jpg
  big: img/gallery-image-one.jpg
  categories:
    - People
    - Places
- title: two
  thumb: img/gallery-image-two.jpg
  big: img/gallery-image-two.jpg
  categories:
    - Objects
    - Places
- title: three
  thumb: img/gallery-image-three.jpg
  big: img/gallery-image-three.jpg
  categories:
    - People
- title: four
  thumb: img/gallery-image-four.jpg
  big: img/gallery-image-four.jpg
  categories:
    - Objects
    - Places
- title: five
  thumb: img/gallery-image-five.jpg
  big: img/gallery-image-five.jpg
  categories:
    - Objects
- title: eight
  thumb: img/gallery-image-eight.jpg
  big: img/gallery-image-eight.jpg
  categories:
    - Places
- title: seven
  thumb: img/gallery-image-seven.jpg
  big: img/gallery-image-seven.jpg
  categories:
    - Places
- title: six
  thumb: img/gallery-image-six.jpg
  big: img/gallery-image-six.jpg
  categories:
    - Objects
    - People
 - title: bla
  thumb: img/gallery-image-six.jpg
  big: img/gallery-image-six.jpg
  categories:
    - Objects
    - People
---
<div class="portfolioFilter">

    <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">Alle</a>
    {% for cat in page.categories %}
        <a href="#" data-filter=".{{ cat | slugify }}">{{cat}}</a>
    {% endfor %}

</div><br>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  {% for item in page.images %}
  <div class="grid-item{% for cat in item.categories %} {{cat | slugify}}{% endfor %}">
    <a class="example-image-link" href="{{item.big}}" data-lightbox="example-set" ><img src="{{item.thumb}}"/></a>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
Error reading file /Users/maxborm/Desktop/lukawebsite/gallery.html: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indentation is very important in Liquid, and you have to make sure you have the right amount of spaces when declaring collections.

In your case, you have an extra space before `- title: bla` which is causing the error.

i.e. you have:

```
 - title: bla
```

when you should have:

```
- title: bla
```